# Failed to resolve: com.google.android:flexbox:0.2.1

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm building old android app then i counter this error, how to download it?

Failed to resolve: com.google.android:flexbox:0.2.1

Comment: try adding allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library is hosted on jcenter at this moment.
Add to your top build.gradle file:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```